# Trigger a button when exactly 13 characters in text field

Tags: java, swing

I have a text field and a Search button. If the user enters precisely 13 digits (a barcode) then I want to trigger the Search automatically.

I have a DocumentListener on the text field and am processing the insertUpdate method to determine that 13 digits have been entered. I could call the search code directly at that point (and it does work) but although the 13th character has been typed, it isn't actually displayed on the screen until the search has completed.

I would prefer instead to trigger the Search button and have tried two ways:

```
DocumentListener dlBarcode = new DocumentAdaptor() {
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        String value = jtBarcode.getText();
        if (isBarcode(value)) {
            ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent((Object)jbSearch,
                             ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(ae);
        }
    }
};
```

The second is to use:

```
jbSearch.dispatch(ae);
```

Neither method appears to cause the ActionListener on jbSearch to be triggered. Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

camickr's suggestion of using invokeLater strangely didn't work as the 13th character didn't get painted until the search had finished. Mark's comment suggesting using a SwingWorker did the trick. My DocumentListener code now looks like:

```
DocumentListener dlBarcode = new DocumentAdaptor() {
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    String value = jtBarcode.getText();
    if (isBarcode(value)) {
        PerformSearch ps = new PerformSearch(value);
        ps.execute();
    }
}
```

And my PerformSearch looks like:

```
class PerformSearch extends SwingWorker<Product, Void> {
private String key = null;
public PerformSearch(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
@Override
protected Product doInBackground() throws Exception {
    return soap.findProduct(this.key);
}
protected void done() {
    Product p = null;
    try {
         p = get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    }
    prod = p;
    if (prod != null) {
        ... populate text fields
    }
    else {
        ... not found dialog
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try programatically "click" the button.  It's not being pressed, so why try to fool your code into thinking it is?  Separating an action from the gesture that performed the action is an important principle to follow.  By analogy, think of the ignition on your car.  Turning the key triggers the ignition.  So if I wanted to design a remote car starter, would I create a mechanical robot that physically inserts and turns a key, or should my system simply signal the ignition directly?

Simply define a method, call it `performSearch` or whatever, and have both your `ActionListener` on the button and your `DocumentListener` each call that method on their own.

One note: don't forget to actually register your document listener with the text control you're using.

Answer (score 2):

> I could call the search code directly at that point (and it does work) but although the 13th character has been typed, it isn't actually displayed on the screen until the search has completed.

Wrap the call to the search code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). This will place the search at the end of the Event Dispatch Thread, so the text field will be updated before the search is started.

```
DocumentListener dlBarcode = new DocumentAdaptor() {
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        String value = jtBarcode.getText();
        if (isBarcode(value)) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    invokeSearchMethod();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I totally missed him saying that.  This is close to a real answer, but I would personally suggest using a SwingWorker instead to do the search in the background and then make the updates to the UI later.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I have tried using invokeLater but the 13th character still only gets painted once the search has finished. From the docs of invokeLater I would have thought the Event Dispatch thread would complete painting the text field before calling the search but seemingly not. I will try using SwingWorker next.